# Mongodb: How to merge $facet output 2 by 2?

Tags: mongodb

Playground:https://mongoplayground.net/p/YUV_fReyGsr
I have following query. I need to combine the result 2 by 2. Meaning I need to combine facet "1","2" as a result and facet "3","4" as another result. It's guaranteed that the number of facet will be even. Also, each pair of facet should get at most one record(it might not matter)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "1": [
        {
          $match: {
            "ID": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          $match: {
            "array.ID": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "3": [
        {
          $match: {
            "array.ID": "4"
          }
        }
      ],
      "4": [
        {
          $match: {
            "ID": "4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

The expected result will be

```
[
  {
    "1": [
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "array": [
          {
            "ID": "2",
            "attribute1": "456"
          },
          {
            "ID": "3",
            "attribute1": "567"
          }
        ],
        "attr1": "123"
      }
    ],
    "2": [
      {
        "ID": "4",
        "array": [
          {
            "ID": "5",
            "attr1": "456"
          }
        ],
        "attr1": "123"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using `$concatArrays` operator, along with `$project`.

[Live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tWCB21yQUg4)

### Database

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "attr1": "123",
    "array": [
      {
        "ID": "2",
        "attribute1": "456"
      },
      {
        "ID": "3",
        "attribute1": "567"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "attr1": "123",
    "array": [
      {
        "ID": "5",
        "attr1": "456"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "1": [
        {
          $match: {
            "ID": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          $match: {
            "array.ID": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "3": [
        {
          $match: {
            "array.ID": "4"
          }
        }
      ],
      "4": [
        {
          $match: {
            "ID": "4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "1": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$1",
          "$2"
        ]
      },
      "2": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$3",
          "$4"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

### Result

```
[
  {
    "1": [
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "array": [
          {
            "ID": "2",
            "attribute1": "456"
          },
          {
            "ID": "3",
            "attribute1": "567"
          }
        ],
        "attr1": "123"
      }
    ],
    "2": [
      {
        "ID": "4",
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "array": [
          {
            "ID": "5",
            "attr1": "456"
          }
        ],
        "attr1": "123"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. My API need to handle multiple queries(it comes with indexes 1 ,2 3..) so that's why I need to used facet to query and identify them. Now each index in the request creates 2 indexes in my facet query. That's why I need to combine the facet 2 by 2 so that it can return the corresponding index of the request.

Comment: Hey @harryk I was able to figure this out. See my updated answer.